# Google Chrome draws the polygon when using map tag in HTML

Tags: html, google-chrome, dictionary

Heres my Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p>Click on the sun or on one of the planets to watch it closer:</p>
<img src="planets.gif" width="145" height="126" alt="Planets" usemap="#planetmap">
<map name="planetmap">
<area shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" alt="Sun" href="sun.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" alt="Mercury" href="mercur.htm">
<area shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" alt="Venus" href="venus.htm">
</map>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when i click and hold at any of the image map in google chrome, it draws the line defining the area which is weird and how should i avoid it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this before the `<body>` tag

```
<style>
area {border:0; outline: 0;}
</style>
```